# How do you calculate the kernel of the substitution homorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[e^{i2\pi /r}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots-of-unity

I can do that for "easier" substitutions like $x \mapsto i$, but I don't know enough about primitive $rth$ roots yet.  Does this require pieces of Galois theory?  $r$ is a positive integer.  I think if we let $(a,r) = 1, a\neq 1$, then $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[e^{i2\pi a/r}]$ (subst. hom) has kernel $I = (x^r - 1)$.

Comment: are we to assume $r$ is an integer?

Comment: Yes, a positive integer.

Comment: There's no Galois theory involved (as far as I can tell). The kernel contains all polynomials that have $e^{2\pi i/r}$ as a root, and these are exactly the multiples of the $r$-th cyclotomic polynomial

Comment: Interesting, what if instead of $e^{i2\pi/r}$ we used $e^{i2\pi a/r}$, see my edit above.

Comment: @EnjoysMath The kernel is generated by the minimal polynomial of $e^{2\pi i a /r}$. This is independent of $a$ as long as $(a,r) = 1$. If $r > 1$, it is not generated by $x^r - 1$.

Comment: @EnjoysMath Also note that the claim is not true in the familiar substitution $X \mapsto i$. Letting $a = 3$, coprime to $4$, the kernel of $\mathbb{Z}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[-i] = \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is $(X^2 + 1)$, not $X^4 - 1$. The immediate problem there is that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is an integral domain, and $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^4 - 1)$ is not. More generally, $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^r - 1)$ can't give an integral domain if $r > 1$; $X^r - 1$ has the root $X = 1$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find that the kernel is generated by [the cyclotomic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) $\phi_r(x)$.